# How does the C pre-proccesor know what to expand and what not to?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

Let's say we have a macro defined as such

```
#define VALUE_ENTRY(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) \
    case E_##a##e: temp.a##e = d; break;
```

How does the pre-processor know that the 'e' in 'temp' shouldn't be expanded? Is it due to not having `##` in front of the 'e'?

Also, should `temp.a##e` be `temp.##a##e`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preprocessor works on tokens. `e` by itself is a token, whereas the `e` in `temp` is just a character that's part of the larger `temp` token. `##` applies only to tokens.

Furthermore, pasting must produce a single token. Therefore, pasting `.` and `a` is not valid; `temp.a##e` is correct, and pastes `a` and `e` to form `temp.<a><e>`, where `<a>` and `<e>` are the replacement texts of `a` and `e`.

Comment: Does that mean that if I wanted the 'e' in 'temp' to become a token, I could segment it like so - t##e##mp?

Comment: @ph1ash, Almost, but `e` is already a parameter, so it would be replaced. That is, for the call `VALUE_ENTRY(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`, `t##e##mp` would produce `t5mp`.